# Triggering Background task in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have set the `ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger` for triggering background task, for monitoring the changes in the action centre. But it will trigger the back ground task if we remove the notifications in the action centre, but it will not triggering when we add a notifications in the action centre.

Is there any way to monitor the notifications that are added to action centre ?

Comment: Supposing your app is the only entity that adds a notification to the action center, you should not need a monitor from OS for that.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Who is generating the notifications? An external service? The app itself?

More details would get us in the right direction.

Comment: The App itself generating the toast notifications